# Is It Possible To Use Celery With Another Programming Language?

Tags: http, node.js, xml-rpc, celery

I heard about celery and I really like it. But now I'm writing an application with node.js and I have to manage (asynchronous) tasks and I want to use celery to this. I've installed it in my development environment and played around with some python scripts.  It all works well but I want to "call" the tasks with node.js. Has anyone tried to do something like this (with any programming language)?

I saw [this example](https://github.com/ask/celery/tree/master/examples/celery_http_gateway), but the base of this HTTP Gateway idea is a django application and I don't want to create a django app to only handle these calls.

I thought about creating a SimpleXMLRPCServer and use the [node-xmlrpc module](https://github.com/baalexander/node-xmlrpc) to connect with that. What do you think? There is a better way to do this? Is there another app or service that works natively with node.js?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

Celery will force you to inherit a whole Python stack for a simple message queue - seems like a messy pain to me. Check out [coffee-resque](https://github.com/technoweenie/coffee-resque) for a simple and native solution.